# What's a tight way to reference a variable that may not be defined in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have a few local variables in my partials which may or may not be passed by the template that renders them, for instance: `on_question_page`.  If I'm on the page I pass it as true but elsewhere I skip it.

The problem is that I can't reference that variable directly because in the places it isn't defined it throws an error.

This means that I end up with a lot of code like this at the top of my partials:

```
on_question_page = defined?(on_question_page) ? on_question_page : false
```

Messy. Is there a cleaner way to access these optional variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on_question_page ||= false` to assign `false` if `on_question_page` is undefined or `false` or `nil`, that is, something which evaluates to `false` when tested with boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

you might use `||=` operator

```
on_question_page ||= false
```

Comment: That was the answer - I voted the top one on the screen correct though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the default value at a position which is always included and overriding it in your partial?

That way you do not need to check whether it is available and you could even change the default value easily if required.

Comment: That would work but I wanted something more localised - the ||= solution did it in the end

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to use bindings and a helper:

```
# whatever_helper.rb
def local_set(ref, view_binding)
  eval(ref.to_s, view_binding)
rescue NameError
  false
end

# my_neet_view.html.erb
<h1>Question</h1>

<%= local_set("on_question_page", binding) %>
```

Bindings allow us to pass the evaluation context of the view in to a helper and do all the messy work in there. This moves the logic out of the view and in to a helper.

Comment: OK, my solution is waaay more complicated. I'd never thought of somewhere I'd use bindings before and I think I got ahead of myself.